# Help me Identify this Font?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

What font is used in '&' on the image below -

[image]

It'd be a great help to know, thanks for any help. :)

Comment: Looks simply like Helvetica to me.

Comment: Yep. Helvetica...and I assume being uses in a highly ironic way given the subject matter?

Comment: @Scott Am I wrong?

Comment: @ilan "Swiss" = "Helvetica". At one time Bitstream managed to license a huge amount of 3rd party typefaces, but not the actual names. Hence a lot of Bitstream's fonts are the same but with just a different name.

Answer (score 4):

Looks very similar to [Swiss 721 Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/bitstream/swiss-721/bold-italic/)

[image]

ADD

[Neue Haas Grotesk](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/linotype/neue-haas-grotesk/) looks similar too (not bold example):

[image]

Comment: Seems like a very good fit. The font is not _quite_ Helvetica.

Comment: Neue Hass Grotesk was the original name of Helvetica :) LinoType did alter it a bit and made it a more inclusive face when they adopted it. So, it's not quite Helvetica today, but it is the basis on which Helvetica was created.

Comment: @Scott thx for important comment.

Comment: And to add to Scott's comment, Swiss *is* a licensed Helvetica. Just under a different name.